# Projected Coordinate System for COGO descriptions?

Tags: coordinate-system, cogo

I am COGOing a legal description from 1950.  When I COGO the legal description it does not match the boundaries from the data in our database.  I suspect it is the coordinate systems not matching.  The projection my company uses is NAD_1983_StatePlane_Utah_Central_FIPS_4302_Feet.

Is there a way to determine what the coordinate system would be from a document from the 1950's?

Comment: What is "COGO"?!

Comment: @bugmenot123 - hover over the tag.

Comment: I've given an extended comment as an answer, but really, you need to provide more details of your problem before a proper detailed answer can be given. What tools are you using? In what manner do the "boundaries not match"? Give us some sample data. (Use the **[edit]** button to add the extra information.)

Comment: Adding a reference like https://www.codot.gov/business/engineeringapplications/assets/documentation/COGOManual.pdf would help GIS youngsters.

Answer (score 2):

Legal descriptions have bearings and distances, not rectangular coordinates. While the bearings may be similar to those of some projected coordinate system, they are usually only correct relative to existing bearing lines on a cadastral map. Also, while the distances will be similar to those of some projected coordinate system, they are "ground" distances rather than "grid" distances. If there are coordinates on the cadastral map there should also be notes describing the coordinate system used.